# PC Specification and Gaming

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gaming

I spent £1,200 on a PC about five years ago. Here is the specification:

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 950 @ 3.07 GHZ
RAM: 6 GB
Type: 64 Bit
Monitor: BENQ G925HDA (Analog). With a VGA to DVI converter.
Display Adapter: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series
Motherboard: ASUSTeK Computer INC
Operating System: Windows 10
BIOS: American MegaTrends Inc 0502 16/11/2010
```

I was looking at the minimum requirements to play: 'Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare".

**Processor**

The minimum requirement is a: Intel Core i3-3225 @ 3.30GHz. This is a 3rd generation (Ivy Bridge) processor. I have a Core I7 930, which is a 1st Generation (Nehalem - Bloomfield). How do you compare different chips (I3 and I5) from different generations. For example, is an I3 3rd generation superior to a I7 1st generation in terms of gaming?

This processor fits into a LGA 1366 socket, which I believe is now historic.  Therefore I will have to replace the motherboard as well?

**Graphics Card**

I have a AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series. I guess I am going to have to upgrade as the minimum requirement is: AMD Radeon HD 7850 2GB?

Comment: Based on benchmark figures I should imagine your CPU would be perfectly  fine for most games but you would need a better graphics card for any recent demanding games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "is an I3 3rd generation superior to a I7 1st generation in terms of gaming? "

When you want to compare different cpus, it's usefull to have this [list](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/cpu-hierarchy,4312.html)
The list is mostly based on gaming performance of the cpus. As for your cpu it is slightly behind the reccomended i3, but i think that is a small gap and it shouldn't affect much this specific game (Infinite Warfare). The website says that you should upgrade your cpu with another that is at least 3 tiers higher than your current, or you won't feel any difference in performance.

- "This processor fits into a LGA 1366 socket, which I believe is now historic. Therefore I will have to replace the motherboard as well?"

Yes, the socket lga 1366 has been discontinued. If you want to buy a brand new cpu you will need a new motherboard (newest intel sockets are LGA 1151 and LGA 2011-v3). I don't really reccomend buying old used CPUs, because there are no replacement motherboards in the case yours fail.

- "I guess I am going to have to upgrade as the minimum requirement is: AMD Radeon HD 7850 2GB? "

In this case yes, if you want a smoother gameplay, a faster gpu will be necessary.

Comment: They also have the same list for graphics cards [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gpu-hierarchy,4388.html) . Keep your eye open though, they update it pretty much every month.